# Facebook Like button - prevent XFBML version from resizing height

Tags: javascript, facebook, height

I'm trying to use the XFBML version of the Facebook Like button. On a page with zero likes, the main problem is the order of events when the page loads:

- HTML loads
- Like button loads
- Button expands height, pushing content below it down
- Button sees it has no likes
- Button reduces height, moving content below back up

This happens regardless of how the [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) is loaded (standard or asynchronous) and if "show faces" are enabled/disabled.

Is there a way to prevent this distracting automatic resizing from happening?

Here's a [test page](http://bit.ly/egaWXR) showing the behavior.

Comment: I've been wondering about that for a while, too. I don't have a satisfactory answer, other than maybe "double-storing" the likes and Facebook user ids on your side (but that may be overly complex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been frustrated by this many times over. I finally cooked up a hack in jQuery. It works in Chrome, FF and Safari. Sorry I am not near an IE computer.. but the concept should remain.

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:block;float:left;width:450px;min-height:35px;">

    <div id="like" style="display:none;float:left;width:450px;height:35px;overflow:hidden;">

        <fb:like href="" show_faces="true" width="450" font=""></fb:like>

    </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#like').delay(500).fadeIn(500,function(){ $(this).css({'height':"inherit",'overflow':"inherit"}); });
```

**Explanation**

First, create a div with a min-height of *35px*, then create a child div with an id of *like*, display of *none*, height of *35px* and overflow of *hidden*.

With jQuery, reference the *like* div and delay a fade in. Upon completion of that fade in, reset the css attributes (height and overflow) to *inherit*.

In theory this allows the like button do it's little freak out behind the scenes and then gracefully brining it into the page.

Hope this helps, and or Facebook just fixes this.

Comment: It doesn't, but it cuts out half of the over pop the like button does (expand out and shrink back), as it only expands out (for the faces). 
Also the question asked for a page with zero likes. It's a hack and I wish Facebook would just fix it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could "double-store" the likes and Facebook user ids on your side (using `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) { ... });`) and then check if your logged-in Facebook user has friends who liked your page.

That may be overly complex, though.